# Position inline form next to navbar-brand in Bootstrap 4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I am trying to position an inline form and navbar-brand next to each other (horizontally) on a bootstrap 4 navbar but instead they are vertically stacked.

The code I am using is below:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-faded">
  <h1 class="navbar-brand">MyBrand</h1>
  <form class="form-inline">
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-success" type="button">This should be on the same line as the brand</button>
  </form>
</nav>
```

And I have a bootly demo here http://www.bootply.com/sOvVSY1TtM#

Welcome any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Updated 2018***

**Bootstrap 4** `navbar-toggleable-*` has been replaced with `navbar-expand-*`.
 Simply use **`navbar-expand`** for a Navbar that *remains* **horizontal** on all screen widths.

---

The Bootstrap 4 Navbar is now vertical (for mobile) by default. To override this, use `navbar-toggleable-xl` so that it remains horizontal...

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-xl navbar-light bg-faded">
  <h1 class="navbar-brand">MyBrand</h1>
  <form class="">
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-success" type="button">New Note</button>
  </form>
</nav>
```

http://www.bootply.com/whbzZorNyy

---

Related: [Bootstrap 4 Fixed top navbar shows collapsed and hides content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49674001/bootstrap-4-fixed-top-navbar-shows-collapsed-and-hides-content)