# Bootstrap 4 Fixed top navbar shows collapsed and hides content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have already tried lot of threads on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11124777/twitter-bootstrap-navbar-fixed-top-overlapping-site) and also this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45962300/vertical-fixed-top-navbar-on-bootstrap-4-beta) but couldn't get it done. I am trying to make one fixed navbar on top with bootstrap 4. But looks like the navbar is shifting towards top. I have tried by adding padding in `css` as suggested by official doc also but the content is shifting not the fixed navabar.
Here is the default navbar image
[image]

And this is the fixed navbar image I am getting 
[image]
I don't know what I am missing in this. Here is the code

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-light bg-light">
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item-active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#/">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#/product">Products</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#/services">Services</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#/career">Career</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#/contact">Contact Us</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Any help on this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the **`navbar-expand`** class to make the navbar show, otherwise it will be collapsed (since mobile is the default state).

https://www.codeply.com/go/HQbDGFwvxp

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item-active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#/">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#/product">Products</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#/services">Services</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#/career">Career</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#/contact">Contact Us</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

If you don't intent to use the mobile collapsible menu, just remove the navbar-collapse...

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand navbar-light bg-light">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item-active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#/">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#/product">Products</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#/services">Services</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#/career">Career</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#/contact">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**Similar questions**
[Bootstrap Navbar list items/links not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42708278/bootstrap-navbar-list-items-links-not-showing)
[Disable responsive navbar in bootstrap 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41945176/disable-responsive-navbar-in-bootstrap-4)

---

**Note:** When using the `fixed-top` Navbar, [Bootstrap recommends](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/#placement) adding padding to the top of the body to prevent content from being hidden by the Navbar..

```
body {
    padding-top: 56px;
}
```

[Demo](https://www.codeply.com/go/HQbDGFwvxp)

Comment: Anything in css ?

Comment: Because my content are hiding with the fixed navbar

Comment: Yes, you do need `padding-top` on the body for the fixed navbar, but that's different than the problem described with the navbar collapsed. The navbar isn't showing because you don't have `navbar-expand`.

Comment: Thanks mate for the help been scratching it since long. newbie to bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
nav{
   position:fixed;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-light bg-light" style="position:fixed;">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item-active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#/">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#/product">Products</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#/services">Services</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#/career">Career</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#/contact">Contact Us</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

You should change the right class in the css page

Answer (score -1):

remove the fixed-top and use css

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item-active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#/">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#/product">Products</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#/services">Services</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#/career">Career</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#/contact">Contact Us</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: remove the fixed-top and use css